# Why does IE create an empty region when I use margins?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, margin

I'm facing strange behavior with IE over margins. After investigating with the developer tools, it looks like IE creates empty space between where the element was originally and the new location. However, it also looks like Firefox simply moves the element without creating the empty space. Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div style="margin-top: 50px;">Hello World</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's an image showing what I mean:
  [image: IE Developer Tools]

Is this normal behavior? How can I avoid this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is. That orange section represent the 50px margin you have assigned to the element. The `margin` property effectively creates a space in any specified direction wherein no other elements may sit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The yellow "empty space" is the space occupied by the top-margin. If you switch to the Layout tab of the DOM Explorer's right pane, you'll see that yellow is used to denote margin areas, whereas Firefox doesn't show the margins this way.

Comment: Ok, well then I guess that makes sense. 8 minutes until I can accept your answer, sorry about that!